# when using hide/show in jquery I can't remember divs position

Tags: jquery, show-hide

When I am using hide() in jquery on some div element (which is very long, so it has scroll), when I use show() in jquery it can't remember position of the scroll. Do you have any solution how can I remember that position?

Comment: you need to post some example code and better describe what's happening.  It's going to be tough to help you only the information provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSFiddle that works: http://jsfiddle.net/u7MxW/

Hope this helps